# How to disable 5G support of my wifi

Tags: 18.04, wireless, network-manager, iwlwifi

I am using ubuntu 18.04.6, as in tegra-ubuntu 4.9.253-tegra.
Now I want to make it such that I won't be able to scan nor connect to 5G networks, is there any way other than modifying the driver, such that 5G support could be turned off?
Currently, I am able to change connected connections using nm-connection-editor.
Is there way to disable 5Ghz channels ,or disable 802.11n mode , or anything like that.
sudo iw dev wlan0 set freq 2412 shows resource busy,even if there are no connections.

Comment: Please be aware that Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, which was released in 2018-April (thus the 18.04) had 5 years of *standard* support life, is nearing the end of those five years. You can use `ubuntu-support-status` to confirm if your system is still *supported*. Either way, if the machine is on-line, you should plan to *release-upgrade* asap unless you plan to use ESM/Pro, but please note ESM/Pro releases are not on-topic here when standard support ends.   The kernel you mention is **not** a supported Ubuntu 18.04 LTS kernel, so you're not likely running a Ubuntu system (just Ubuntu based)

Comment: Please explain why you would want to do this. 5 gHz is almost always faster and is generally preferable. Perhaps there is a better solution to your issue.

Comment: As for why i am disabling 5G, it is my task assigned to be, most probably to limit liability while creating a product, Yes, i believe i am using ubuntu based system, however i saw there is nearly not much difference from base ubuntu,  Any way thanks for all your replies, if there is any solution or reference i could use , unfortunately i can't change kernal for now, maybe in future after prototyping of the device i am currently is complete , it will be helpful. Again Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, we can't retroactively close as EOL. Feel free to answer for later versions though (we may not be able to test answers for 18.04). If you upgrade your system, Darsan K Pradeep,, you can edit your question.